# PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, docker

I am currently updating our docker image in Azure.From this image `appsvcorg/alpine-php-mysql:0.3` to this `leonzhang77/alpine-php-mysql:0.31`.

After pasting and save it on container,restart app, when I browse my site (*linux.rapidvisa.com* , *Wordpress 4.9.7,PHP7*) that error *appeared.MySQL* also cannot connect to `var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

I tried to fix it. I can see on my `phpinfo.php` that `MySQL/MySQLi` is not there or not running.

I am new in this Docker and Azure environment although I managed to enter into SSH and do some tweaking but no luck.

I tried to type `sudo apt-get install blah`..but **command not found**.Whenever I typed major commands always **-ash: command not found**. Can somebody advise me what to do?

Comment: probably bad base image. its not like it modifies the image before it runs it

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what the exact problem is with your docker construct but your second one is the alpine distribution.

in alpine linux there is an other package manager system.

you have to use **apk**.

like: `apk update` or `apk add htop`